# OpenCV, I get segmentation and cant find it

Tags: c++, opencv, segmentation-fault

I am pretty new with C++ so i really don't know what went wrong. I have a function here which to get the orignal_image and make it to a oilpaiting.
https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/471994/OilPaintEffect
I followed these steps but I still get a Segmentation fault.

```
cv::Mat getFilteredImage(const cv::Mat &original_image,
                     int radius,
                     int levels)
{


for(int i=0;i<original_image.rows;i++)
{
    for(int j=0;j<original_image.cols;j++)
    {
        for(int k=-radius;k<=radius;k++)
        {
            for(int l=-radius;l<=radius;l++)
            {
                int IB = original_image.at<cv::Vec3b>(j,i)[0]; 
                 int IG = original_image.at<cv::Vec3b>(j,i)[1]; 
                int IR = original_image.at<cv::Vec3b>(j,i)[2]; 



                int intervall = floor(((double)((IR+IG+IB)/3.0) * (levels/255.0)));//eine Pixel intensität errechen

                if(intervall>255)
                {
                    intervall = 255;
                }
                std::vector<int> intensityCount;
                intensityCount[intervall]++;

                int averageB[intervall];
                int averageG[intervall];
                int averageR[intervall];

                averageB[intervall] += IB;
                averageG[intervall] += IG;
                averageR[intervall] += IR;


                }


            }

                int Curmax=0;
                int maxIndex;

                for(int nI = 0; nI<256;nI++)
                {
                    if(intensityCount[nI]>Curmax)  //this is not allowed
                    {
                        Curmax = intensityCount[nI];
                        maxIndex = nI;

                    }



        }


    }

}


cv::Mat output = cv::Mat::zeros(original_image.size(),
                                original_image.type());




return output;
}
```

Comment: How have you defined `intensityCount`? Also: You are using signed intenger `levels` to compute `intervall`. (Which is also an int)

Comment: i just followed the steps thought it might work( https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/471994/OilPaintEffect) the level ist for the intensity. I heard in openCV is easier to use double or float to calculate the intensity

Answer (score 1):

```
std::vector<int> intensityCount;
intensityCount[intervall]++;
```

This doesn't do what you whink it does. The first line declares and initialises an **empty** vector. This means that your second line will access uninitialised memory, which is the cause for your segfault. To fix this, either initialise you vector with a given size (`std::vector<int>
 intensityCount(yourSizeHere)`) or use [push back](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/push_back) or [emplace back](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/emplace_back).